# Macro for drawing a right triangle with options for lengths automatically

Tags: macros, options

I am hoping to write a macro so that in the options, I can change the horizontal length and the vertical length to produce an image automatically.  I only use the \hordisplay  because some of the lengths don't scale well. If someone could suggest a better way to do that, that would be great too.

I would like to draw a triangle and be able to ask for the input \hor (the horizontal length and also ask for \vertical  the vertical length.  Then have tikz draw me a nice to scale diagram.

```
   \documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \newcommand{\hor}{3.24}
    \newcommand{\vertical}{1.68}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hordisplay}{\hor*10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vertdisplay}{\vertical*10}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\hor,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\vertical);
    \draw(A)--node[midway, below]{$\hordisplay$ m}(B)--(C)--node[midway,left]{$\vertdisplay$  m}cycle;
    \draw[|-|,blue] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]B)--node[black,pos=0.5,fill=white,yshift=1mm]{$x$}([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]C);
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[draw=blue,size=.2](B,A,C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please specify clearly what input values you want to supply, and what the expected output is? Without any information `\newcommand{\hor}{3.24}
    \newcommand{\vertical}{1.68}` appear to have no motivation.

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm still new at asking the questions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal using pgf keys. You can use it as `\MyTrianle{h=3.24,v=1.68}`, the order in which you specify the parameters does not matter. The optional argument can be fed with keys like `thick` or scalings etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}%<- if you need this line, it is time to update your TeX installation

\newcommand{\MyTrianle}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,#1,
    triangle/.cd,h/.initial=1,v/.initial]
    \tikzset{triangle/.cd,#2}
    \newcommand{\hor}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/h}}
    \newcommand{\vertical}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/v}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hordisplay}{\hor*10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vertdisplay}{\vertical*10}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\hor,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\vertical);
    \draw(A)--
    node[midway, below]{$\pgfmathprintnumber\hordisplay\,$m}(B)--(C)--
    node[midway,left]{$\pgfmathprintnumber\vertdisplay\,$m}cycle;
    \draw[|-|,blue] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]B)--node[black,pos=0.5,fill=white,yshift=1mm]{$x$}([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]C);
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[draw=blue,size=.2](B,A,C);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\MyTrianle{h=3.24,v=1.68}
\MyTrianle{h=4.5,v=2.7}
\MyTrianle{h=pi,v=e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always upgrade the macro by adding more keys.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

%\usetkzobj{all}%<- if you need this line, it is time to update your TeX installation

\newcommand{\MyTrianle}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,#1,
    triangle/.cd,h/.initial=1,v/.initial,unit/.initial=m,factor/.initial=10]
    \tikzset{triangle/.cd,#2}
    \newcommand{\hor}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/h}}
    \newcommand{\vertical}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/v}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hordisplay}{\hor*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/factor}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vertdisplay}{\vertical*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/factor}}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\hor,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\vertical);
    \draw(A)--
    node[midway,below]{$\pgfmathprintnumber\hordisplay\,$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/unit}}(B)--(C)--
    node[midway,left]{$\pgfmathprintnumber\vertdisplay\,$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangle/unit}}cycle;
    \draw[|-|,blue] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]B)--node[black,pos=0.5,fill=white,yshift=1mm]{$x$}([xshift=1mm,yshift=2.5mm]C);
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[draw=blue,size=.2](B,A,C);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\MyTrianle{h=3.24,v=1.68}
\MyTrianle{h=4.5,v=2.7,factor=100}
\MyTrianle{h=pi,v=e,unit=cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  This will work really well,  When you say optional argument can be passed, can you help me understand what you mean?

Comment: @E.Yu Try e.g. `\MyTrianle[very thick]{h=3.24,v=1.68}`.

Comment: oh yes.  I see.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi.  I appreciate all your help as I continue to learn about latex.  Is there a way that I can add the units as an option?  I'm wondering if I can change the [2] into a [3] then add a unit/.initial=m (but I don't know how to do this properly.  I can't get it to compile

Comment: @E.Yu I added a second version, which comes with more keys, and illustrates how you can add keys.

Comment: You are amazing.  So grateful!!!